# Jssor force slide from an external html element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jssor

I would like to force the jssor slide when I click a button.

When I click the small images (thumbs) in the slider the function NavigationClickHandler is called, and this function is defined inside another function:

```
function JssorSlider(elmt, options) {
(...)
        function NavigationClickHandler(index, relative) {
              (...)
        }
}
```

In order to slide when I click a button, I do the following:

```
jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$("slider1_container", options);
jssor_slider1.NavigationClickHandler(0, 'true');
```

but I get the following error in Firebug:

*TypeError: jssor_slider1.NavigationClickHandler is not a function*

How can I call the function NavigationClickHandler in the onclick event of the button?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$("slider1_container", options);
//call $PlayTo when a button is clicked
jssor_slider1.$PlayTo(3);
```

reference:

http://www.jssor.com/testcase/api-play-pause-goto-playto-test.source.html
http://www.jssor.com/development/reference-api.html